# Wrapping elements inside a div tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to wrap a couple of elements inside a `<div>` tag using jQuery.

I first append a overall wrapper, then a header element and then a span element.  I'm trying to wrap the header and span in a container div, followed a few posts on here and read through the docs, but just cant get it to work, currently it looks like this:

```
$(responseData).each(function(i) {
   var CountryN= this.CountryN;
   var Subtitles= this.subTitle;
   var $mainWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass('mainWrap');
   $mainWrapper.append($('<h4/>').text(CountryN));
   $mainWrapper.append($('<span/>').text(Subtitles).addClass('subT'));
})
```

which results in this:

```
<div class="mainWrap">
   <h4>USA</h4>
   <span class="subT">$12.1,563m, D.A.C = 01/01/2013</span>
</div>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is this structure:

```
<div class="mainWrap">
   <div class="countryWrap">
      <h4>USA</h4>
      <span class="subT">$12.1,563m, D.A.C = 01/01/2013</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

My page has several of these sections (each within their own mainWrap), tried using wrap all, but it needs to wrap both the header and the subtitle so not sure how i would select them (if that is the best way of going about it)

Comment: Can you show a demonstrative snippet of what `responseData` would contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want multiple countryWraps inside the mainWrap, in that case, you will have to create the mainWrap outside of the each loop.

```
var $mainWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass('mainWrap');

$(responseData).each(function(i) {
   var CountryN= this.CountryN;
   var Subtitles= this.subTitle;
   var $countryWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass('countryWrap');
   $countryWrapper.append($('<h4/>').text(CountryN));
   $countryWrapper.append($('<span/>').text(Subtitles).addClass('subT'));
   $mainWrapper.append($countryWrapper);
})
```

Comment: This method worked the way i needed, thanks.  Just needed to bring the mainwrapper inside the loop because (poor naming) it's meant for mainCountryWrapper   But other than that great.  Don't know why i couldnt get it working, tried something almost identical.  Your code works great though!  Thanks

Comment: Cool. Sometimes things are like that. :) Please accept the answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has several to wrap the contents of HTML. I believe wrapInner() would resolve this issue.

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/

http://jsfiddle.net/ynLmhk83/

```
jQuery(".mainWrap").wrapInner('<div class="countryWrap"></div>');
```